# Task.ContinueWith() parent task doesn't wait for child task to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Since I was understanding the `Task` in context of nested task, I really don't understand that- Why the 3rd print before 2nd print?

Even though, I have used `Task.WaitAll(t)`, it print *3rd* line before *2nd* line.

**Code:**

```
public static void Main()
        {

            Task t = new Task(
                () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("1st print...");
                });
           t.ContinueWith(
                x =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("2nd print...");
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            t.Start();
            Task.WaitAll(t);

            Console.WriteLine("3rd print...");
            Console.Read();

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It produce the same result even if I use 'TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent' with child task's option.

Comment: @Andrey Of course, we have the duplicate question, but the answer of this duplicate question relies on creating an array of tasks Task[] which is the solution I know. But I want to know the answer without creating the array Task[].

Comment: I want to use my car to go to places without putting gas on it, but it won't move!

Comment: @Jcl I understand your concern, but I want to know that is there ANY way to accomplish this by creating child tasks, NOT totally separate task.

Comment: The result of the `ContinueWith` function is still a child task... you just need to wait for it. My answer is not doing anything that was not in your code, except waiting for the continuation/child task

Comment: If it is SO, then what is the point to use 'ContinueWith' option, I can also create another task and perform the action. then, Why should I use 'ContinueWith' any more??

Comment: In your example code, there's absolutely no need for a continuation task (you could just put the second `Console.Write` and `Thread.Sleep` on the main task), but it is YOUR code, not mine. If you want something else, write your question accordingly.

Comment: @nunu there is no solution except for passing all tasks you want to wait to WaitAll, that's why duplicate. Nothing can be added to what is written in that question. There is no `WaitAllAndChildren` method.

Comment: I think you are just misunderstanding what your code does: `Task.Wait` is waiting for the main task to end. When it ends, it boths continues execution on the main thread (thus writes "3rd line") and the main task also runs the continuation task at the same time (thus writes "2nd line"). The order of these last two is not guaranteed, unless you wait for this second (child) task somehow. That "somehow" is indicating `Task.Wait` that it should also wait for this child task. There's no other way.

Comment: Thanks @Jcl. Actually, what I was understanding is- If I use 'TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent' option with child task, I thought that the child task is attached to parent. Now if I wait for parent task, the child task will be automatically  waited.

Comment: Attached tasks, to put it easily, only indicate the status and exceptions should be "shared" between the parent and child tasks... it doesn't "extend your original task without creating another" (furthermore, you are not using `AttachedToParent` on your sample code)

Comment: You should read and try to understand this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx (it's not easy for a first read, but experiment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wait for the continuation also:

```
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith( /* .. */ );
Task.WaitAll(new [] { t, t2 } );
```

Comment: Thanks @Jcl! BUT, I don't want to create multiple tasks. I want to handle this with single task. Of course, we can create nested tasks in one parent tasks as a child tasks, but NOT totally different task.

Comment: You are using `ContinueWith` so you are already creating a second task... you are just not storing the result of the `ContinueWith` function, but that doesn't mean the task is not created.

Answer (score 4):

You only waited for `t`, not for its continuation. That's why that continuation will run at some time in the future. If it weren't for the `Console.Read` it might never run before the process has exited.

`Task.WaitAll(t)` is equivalent to `t.Wait()` (which you should use instead because it is more idiomatic).

Having it wait for all continuations (maybe recursively) would make for unintuitive behavior and have non-local effects. Remote parts of the program could influence your code.

Comment: Thanks @usr! Now the question is, how would I wait for the nested task to finish??

Comment: Store that task somewhere and also wait on it.

Answer (score 0):

You make an assumption that it should wait for child tasks but there is no base to make such assumptions. From MSDN:

> Task.WaitAll: Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete
>   execution.

And it does exactly what it says. The `ContinueWith` doesn't change the length of original task, it doesn't become longer. It just executes right after.