# How can I wait for the last Task in the chain?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Calling Wait() on a Task only waits until it finishes, not until the last continuation in the chain finishes.

How can I wait for the last Task in the chain?  I would simply put the whole chain in an array and WaitAll on it, but ContinueWith takes a delegate, not a Task to which I can keep a reference.

Comment: Have you looked into `WaitAll`?

Comment: Having some code to share? That will be very helpful for us to answer.

Comment: Store the continuation tasks along with the original one in an array, and use `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: After your editing of the question, `ContinueWith` takes a delegate but **returns** the created `Task`

Comment: I answered just that on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689000/task-continuewith-parent-task-doesnt-wait-for-child-task-to-finish/27689098#27689098 (which seems to be a duplicate in turn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Task.WaitAll()`, which takes an array of tasks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:** In that case, you can use the `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`.

*The ContinueWhenAll method executes the continuationAction delegate when all tasks in the tasks array have completed, regardless of their completion status.*

Here is a psuedo code example:

```
Tasks[] tasks = GetTasks();
var finalTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, completedTasks => {...}); 
finalTask.Wait();
```

There is a non pseudo code example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473(v=vs.110).aspx).